# Xsl number() function not allowing zero

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, apache-fop

I am using xsl:if to check whether the value is numeric or not by using number function in a table column - **column-two**, but it not allowing any zero.
when i checked it by removing xsl:if i am getting 0 in my column cell, else 0's are not present in output.

**My XSL**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
        <xsl:template match="data">
            <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
                <fo:layout-master-set>
                    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="simple"
                        page-height="8.5in" page-width="11in" margin-top=".5in"
                        margin-bottom=".5in" margin-left=".5in" margin-right=".5in">
                        <fo:region-body margin-top="2cm" margin-bottom="2cm" />
                        <fo:region-before extent="2cm" overflow="hidden" />
                        <fo:region-after extent="1cm" overflow="hidden" />
                    </fo:simple-page-master>
                </fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:page-sequence master-reference="simple"
                    initial-page-number="1">
                    <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before">
                        <fo:block font-size="13.0pt" font-family="serif"
                            padding-after="2.0pt" space-before="4.0pt" text-align="center"
                            border-bottom-style="solid" border-bottom-width="1.0pt">
                            <xsl:text>PDF Test</xsl:text>
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:static-content>
                    <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after">
                        <fo:block font-size="12.0pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                            padding-after="2.0pt" space-before="2.0pt" text-align="center"
                            border-top-style="solid" border-bottom-width="1.0pt">
                            <xsl:text>Page</xsl:text>
                            <fo:page-number />
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:static-content>
                    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="data-body" />
                    </fo:flow>
                </fo:page-sequence>
            </fo:root>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="data-body">
            <fo:block text-align="center">
                <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%"
                    border-style="dashed">
                    <fo:table-column border-style="solid" />
                    <fo:table-column border-style="solid" />
                    <fo:table-column border-style="solid" />
                    <fo:table-header>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="table-header" />
                    </fo:table-header>
                    <fo:table-body>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="table-data" />
                    </fo:table-body>
                </fo:table>
            </fo:block>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="table-header">
            <fo:table-row keep-together.within-page="always"
                border-style="solid">
                <fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                        padding-top="3pt">
                        <xsl:value-of select="column-one"></xsl:value-of>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                        padding-top="3pt">
                        <xsl:value-of select="column-two"></xsl:value-of>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                        padding-top="3pt">
                        <xsl:value-of select="column-three"></xsl:value-of>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="table-data">
            <fo:table-row keep-together.within-page="always"
                border-style="solid">
                <fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                        padding-top="3pt">
                        <xsl:value-of select="column-one"></xsl:value-of>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                        padding-top="3pt">
                        <xsl:if test="number(column-two)">
                        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(translate(column-two, ',','.'), '#,###.##')"></xsl:value-of>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="sans-serif"
                        padding-top="3pt">
                        <xsl:value-of select="column-three"></xsl:value-of>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

**My XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
<data-body>
    <table-header>
        <column-one>Column One</column-one>
        <column-two>Column Two</column-two>
        <column-three>Column Three</column-three>
    </table-header>
    <table-data>
        <column-one>One</column-one>
        <column-two>5000</column-two>
        <column-three>Three</column-three>
    </table-data>
    <table-data>
        <column-one>One</column-one>
        <column-two>5000</column-two>
        <column-three>Three</column-three>
    </table-data>
    <table-data>
        <column-one>One</column-one>
        <column-two>0</column-two>
        <column-three>Three</column-three>
    </table-data>
    <table-data>
        <column-one>One</column-one>
        <column-two>0</column-two>
        <column-three>Four</column-three>
    </table-data>
    <table-data>
        <column-one>One</column-one>
        <column-two>2000</column-two>
        <column-three>Four</column-three>
    </table-data>
    <table-data>
        <column-one>One</column-one>
        <column-two>1234</column-two>
        <column-three>Five</column-three>
    </table-data>
    <table-data>
        <column-one>One</column-one>
        <column-two>5666</column-two>
        <column-three>Five</column-three>
    </table-data>
    <table-data>
        <column-one>One</column-one>
        <column-two>5666</column-two>
        <column-three>Five</column-three>
    </table-data>
     </data-body>
</data>
```

Since i need to print empty block in cell if any non numeric characters present, I used this number function in xsl:if to check whether the cell value is numeric to apply comma separator. So if i removed that xsl:if test am getting 0 in output(correct me if the guess is wrong). i am using xsl file with xml file to create PDF using apache fop, thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/xslt/0596000537/re58.html

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding what the `number()` function does. Its purpose is not to check whether a value is a number. Its purpose is to _convert_ a value to a number. michael.hor257k's answer is the right way to check whether a value is a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your test is not the `number()` function. The `number()` function correctly converts a zero to a number. However, the number zero is evaluated to `false()` when converted to a Boolean - and `xsl:if` must return a Boolean result for its `test` expression.

Try instead:

```
<xsl:if test="number(function_number)=number(function_number)">
```

This works because [NaN is never equal to anything, not even to itself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Comparison_with_NaN).

Comment: Hi michael, for clarification..my qns is about number 0 only..not string ZERO..

Comment: I am afraid your clarification makes no sense to me. Your test looks at the value of the `function_number` element. That value is a string until you convert it to another type.

Comment: Thanks for your solution michael..I misunderstood number() function in xsl:if test..i tried with your solution it completely works